# Existence of a function satisfying the above condition?

Tags: analysis

Here is a question I asked to myself. Does there exist a function $f(z)$ satisfying the following conditions:

- $f(z)$ is continuous on the strip $0 \leq \text{Re}(z) \leq 1$
- $f(z)$ is **holomorphic** on the strip $0 < \text{Re}(z) < 1$
- $f(a)=0$ where $a$ is a fixed real number $0 < a < 1$
- The real part of $f(z)$ is greater of equal to 2 for all $z = it$, ($t \in \mathbb{R}$)
- The real part of $f(z)$ is greater of equal to 2 for all $z = 1+it$, ($t \in \mathbb{R}$)

My best guess so far was $-\frac{2}{a^2}(z^2- a^2)$ but it doesn't satisfy the last condition...

Comment: Do you mean by "smooth" holomorphic? Or is real differentiable infinitely many times sufficient?

Comment: I meant holomorphic but your answer is interesting anyhow. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean a real differentiable function, consider, for instance,
\begin{align*}
f(x+iy)=\frac{2(x-a)^2}{\min\{a^2,(1-a^2)\}}.
\end{align*}
This function is a nonnegative real polynomial (hence infinitely times real differentiable everywhere) with $f(a)=0$ and
\begin{align*}
f(it)&=f(0)=\frac{2a^2}{\min\{a^2,(1-a)^2\}}\geq\frac{2a^2}{a^2}=2, \\
f(1+it)&=f(1)=\frac{2(1-a)^2}{\min\{a^2,(1-a)^2\}}\geq\frac{2(1-a)^2}{(1-a)^2}=2,\qquad t\in\mathbb R. \\
\end{align*}